# C++ Read csv file contain empty cell

Tags: c++, csv

Sorry whether it is a stupid question. I need to read file csv line by line. If file don't have any empty cell, that's OK. But for example, I have one line below:
a,b,c,,,,d
Then I need fill data in a vector like following:
("a","b","c","","","","d")
I tried to used strtok to get rid of "," then push into a vector. Of course it omit 3 above fields. 
Anyone can help me a method to solve this problem.
Thank in advanced!

Comment: Is there a fixed number of entries on each line?

Comment: Nope, because one of fields can be flexible to store many items.

Comment: Did you search at all before asking?  Seems like [any of these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20csv) might help you.

Comment: `strtok` is not the tool for this, because it will ignore whole runs of a delimiter.

Comment: @Ben Voigt Of course, I have searched for a long time. Sorry for my impatient. I still try to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to read a complete line into a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), and put that string into a [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream). Then use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) in a loop on that string-stream to tokenize on the comma.

Do note that this is a very "quick and dirty" solution, and doesn't handle all data that can occur in a CSV file.

Comment: It's not like there's any shortage of feature-rich CSV parsers, why suggest a method that doesn't handle quoted commas?

Comment: Thank Joachim, I had finished. Because I work in MFC so need more time to fix other bugs.